# Removing white space in `script output` in SQL Developer Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I would like to know how to remove white space from my `script out` string. I am getting two tab(8 space) white space while prints two variable concatenated. But the when I remove the last variable then I get a normal script out on my `SQL developer`. How to remove white space for printing two variable concatenated with a string?
Here is the code I am running.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  SUBTYPE name IS CHAR(20);
  SUBTYPE MESSAGE IS VARCHAR2(100);
  salutation name;
  greetings MESSAGE;
BEGIN
  salutation := 'Reader ';
  greetings  := 'Welcome to the World of PL/SQL';
  SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello ' || salutation || greetings);
END;
/
```

Here is the screenshot of the script output.

[image]

How would I remove the white space I marked with red pen on the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use VARCHAR2 instead of CHAR.  CHAR variables get right-padded to the defined length while VARCHAR2 variables only contain the value you assign.